# No such element: Unable to locate element: exception coming in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I am getting below error every time when trying to verify the user credentials after login.

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains(text(),
>   'User: Naveen K')]"}

My code is as follows

## Home page test class

```
@Test(priority = 2)
public void verifyUserNameLabelTest() {

    testUtil.switchToFrame();       

    Assert.assertTrue(homePage.verifyUserName());

}
```

## TestUtil class

```
public void switchToFrame() {

    driver.switchTo().frame("mainpanel");

}
```

## Home page class

```
public boolean verifyUserName() {

    return usernameLabel.isDisplayed();

}
```

My HTML web page source code is as follows

[image: img]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with your xpath, which tries to find user element:

> "//td[contains(text(), 'User: Naveen K')]"}

Correct xpath would be:

```
"//td/font[contains(text(), 'User: Naveen K')]"}
```

Text which you are looking does not belong to td tag, instead it's belong to font tag.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of @rajKamal is nice, but you can also use "." to search the name like that

```
"//td/font[contains(., 'User: Naveen K')]"}
```